# Trying to clone from GitHub, but getting errors: fatal: Unable to create temporary file and Operation not permitted fatal: index-pack failed

Tags: git, clone

Bought a new Macbook Air M1, previously had win machine. Logged in to GitHub, deleted old SSH key, created new one. But when trying to clone repo in VS Code getting this:

**Cloning into 'markdown-portfolio'...
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/Users/air/Desktop/4learning/markdown-portfolio/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Operation not permitted
fatal: index-pack failed
remote: Enumerating objects: 76, done.**

I've even added terminal, GitHub Desktop and VS code to list: Allow the apps to run software locally that does not meet the system's security policy. I'm a newbie, tried to find more info, but couldn't. Thanks.

Comment: Can you clone into some other location?

Comment: Yes, I've tried - same error.

Comment: I have nine repos and just one of them cloned from GitHub.

Comment: Does it work if you put it in a directory that's not `Desktop`, `Documents`, or another special directory?

Comment: `Operation not permitted` is error `EPERM`, returned by the OS when you ask it to do something that requires special privileges. This indicates that your OS installation has something funny going on, because it's requiring that you have special privileges to use your own files. There's nothing *Git* can do about this: you need to ask about macOS instead.

Comment: When I'm trying to clone to different directory I get this: **fatal: could not create work tree dir '/Users/My-first-website': Permission denied**

Comment: Yes, torek, I think it's something with macOS. Going thru all security and permissions settings I can find as well terminal permissions.